# Does WordPress read every plug-in PHP file for every request?

Tags: php, wordpress

This almost answers my question:

[Does PHP read required scripts every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292223/does-php-read-required-scripts-every-request)

But I'm wondering how this works specific to plug-ins.

I've been thinking it is really cool how I can just add any file I want under a plug-in sub-folder, like /plug-ins/my-plugin/my-file.php, and add PHP code to it that will execute on every request, like: `add_action('init','my_init);`

Now I'm starting to wonder how "cool" this really is.  Does this mean WordPress has to do a directory listing to find all files, and then also read all files, for every request?  Or does it have some internal optimizations?  Seems pretty slow if not, compared to something like ASP.NET where most items have to be registered in web.config, and not rechecked unless web.config is modified.

I know you have to activate a plug-in when first installed, but after that you can just add files whenever you want, and they'll "work" on the next request.  Can't imagine how it could avoid doing a directory search for each request, unless it is using something like [FindNextChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be notified by the OS of changes (if all the supported OSs + PHP versions even have that).

Comment: *"Does this mean WordPress has to do a directory listing to find all files, and then also read all files, for every request?"* - yes. This is just the start of Wordpress' truly horrible design

Comment: Wordpress also has a ridiculous number of hooks that it can trigger too

Comment: Kind of what I thought, but so many people use WP, guess I was hoping there was a better reason than "because everyone uses it".  I know that's why I started using it now.. tried DNN, but it just didn't have nearly as many options + existing plug-ins + community support like WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin base file is automatically loaded on every request.
(Usually the base file is /plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php )

However, the plugin author may choose to perform some logic and not load the rest of the PHP files in the plugin if it is not required.

If you had 10 000 small plugins, that would be fairly slow **unless you enable opcode caching (Zend or APC) with nostat**.

If you do that, the performance will be almost on par with having 0 plugins.

PS. Everyone uses WP because it's easy to develop for, has a thriving community and plugin/theme marketplace, and has by far the best admin panel of any CMS today.

Comment: Thanks, and I do like it so far, mostly because there are so many existing options and lots of help easily available.  The caching you mentioned is a perfect example, I just haven't had a chance to read more about that yet.  Most caching has too many issues to be a practical solution, but if that is pretty low-level and robust (like ASP.NET compiler cache), it sounds great.

Comment: Opcode cache usually speeds up page loads by ~30%, and the gain increases the more files you load. The gain can also increase dramatically if you are I/O-bound (that is, your hard drives can't keep up). 

APC and Zend are both fairly stable, at least for Wordpress. Also keep in mind that PHP 5.5 is about 20% faster than PHP 5.3. That can shave off precious milliseconds on your pageloads.

By putting all of the above together you can get a nice speedy environment going. :)